# RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.google.android.instantapps.supervisor

Tags: android

I face this issue on my android app please help me to resolve this, i faced this issue on google pixel devices with android 7.1 or armeabi-v7a. i face this issue in my all app please try to guide me if anyone knows how to solve.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.google.android.instantapps.supervisor, PID: 9365
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.google.android.instantapps.supervisor.ExperimentUpdateReceiver: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Multiple entries with same key: 0=a: 0.0
b: 0
c: 0.9
u: dpg@d1d9
v: -1
 and 0=a: 0.5
b: 0
c: 0.0
u: dpg@cb69
v: -1
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3048)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap18(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1562)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Multiple entries with same key: 0=a: 0.0
b: 0
c: 0.9
u: dpg@d1d9
v: -1
 and 0=a: 0.5
b: 0
c: 0.0
u: dpg@cb69
v: -1
    at ddb.a(PG:13)
    at dms.a(PG:29)
    at bnw.get(PG:8)
    at drh.get(PG:1)
    at bji.get(PG:3)
    at bko.get(PG:3)
    at drh.get(PG:1)
    at bgw.a(PG:17)
    at com.google.android.instantapps.supervisor.ExperimentUpdateReceiver.onReceive(PG:1)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3041)
    ... 8 more
```